# GetProcessioCounters : Error Invalid access to memory location

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to start a process and get GetProcessIoCounters to work without success. I am always getting "Invalid access to memory location".
Could anybody give advice.

Here is my code:

```
  if (!CreateProcessA("c:\\app.exe",NULL,NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    printError(TEXT("CreateProcess Err"));

  PIO_COUNTERS      ioc = 0 ;
  if(!GetProcessIoCounters(hProcess, ioc))
      printError(TEXT("GetProcessIoCounters Err"));
  else          
  {
     wprintf(L"%lu %lu \n", hProcess, ioc->ReadOperationCount);
```

Comment: 'if(!GetProcessIoCounters(hProcess, &ioc))' ??

Comment: `hProcess` ==>> `pi.hProcess`, there is no `hProcess` declared, nor assigned, in any of this code. Post *real* code that reproduces the *real* problem please.

Comment: I tried  "IO_COUNTERS   ioc ;
if (!GetProcessIoCounters(hProcess, &ioc))"  . It worked.

Comment: I agree with you WhozCraig.  It was a typo error. it is pi.hProcess and not hProcess.  Thanks

Comment: @SamirAlShaar I suspected. My point was this: *You should not have to type code into an SO question*. Type the question, yes. Any observations, expectations, conflicts of said-same, explanations of what you're *trying* to do, certainly. But the *code* should already be boiled down to a testable case that (a) *compiles* and (b) exhibits the behavior you're questioning. From there, copy/paste and format, and you know *we* have what *you* have. Along with it, copy/paste any required input data and resulting output results. Something to remember next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While is not clear from where you get the process handle `hProcess`, and supposing that it is correct, in `GetProcessIoCounters` you must provide a pointer to an existing `IO_COUNTERS` structure, not just a pointer to it.

Try:

```
if (!CreateProcessA("c:\\app.exe",NULL,NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    printError(TEXT("CreateProcess Err"));

  IO_COUNTERS ioc = {0} ;
  if(!GetProcessIoCounters(hProcess, &ioc))
      printError(TEXT("GetProcessIoCounters Err"));
  else          
  {
     wprintf(L"%lu %lu \n", hProcess, ioc.ReadOperationCount);
```